# How Can I add Hamburger icon menu in React-Native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I am fairly new to Navigation in react-native but i have been able to pick up few things here now i want o add the Hamburger icon to it to do a Proper Menu bar. Since i am fairly new to this, I need help in every way.

My code Looks something like this

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import {  View, Text, Image , StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

class Home extends React.Component{
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Home',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={{uri:'http://imageholder.freeasphost.net/home.png'}}
        style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
      />
    ),
  };
  render()
  {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text> Welcome to Home screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Profile extends React.Component{
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Profile',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={{uri:'http://imageholder.freeasphost.net/profile.png'}}
        style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
      />
    ),
  };
  render()
  {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome to Profile screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Settings extends React.Component{
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Settings',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={{uri:'http://imageholder.freeasphost.net/settings.png'}}
        style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
      />
    ),
  };
  render()
  {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome to Settings Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:Home
  },
  Settings:{
    screen:Settings
  },
  Profile:{
    screen:Profile
  },
});

const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <MyApp/>  
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
});
```

Like i wanted to use some drawer navigation uri to do it but how to start is the main worry, hence I wanted to know how and what i must do.

Answer (score 0):

I'll always prefer making your own custom component rather than any library.

It's simple,  first download icon like this or your icon and create a view box, and then on the image add touchable opacity so that when a user clicks, it will expand
[image]

will turn into this

[image]

Now steps are like that,

```
renderUnExpanded=()=>(
<View>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.flipState} >
     <Icon />
   </TouchableOpacity>
<View>
)

renderExpanded = () =>(

<View>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.flipState} >
     <Icon />
   </TouchableOpacity>
   <ProfileIcon />
   <SignoutIcon />
<View>

)
```

now flipState will be a function to toggle expanded state,

```
flipState =() => {


this.setState({optionVisible:!this.state.optionVisible})
}
```

and now in render function , show accordingly to state,

```
render(){

return(
{this.state.optionVisible?this.renderExpanded():this.renderUnExpanded()}
)
}
```

hope its clear, otherwise ask any doubts

Comment: You saying I would have to have it as a class? Say class hamburgerMenu extends React.Component? or how exactly?

Comment: yeah, like that, and wherever you want o use , use it like , 

<HAMBURGER />